# Location Update and sending location to server causing iphone heats and restarts automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gps, cllocationmanager

I am fetching user location using CLLlocationManager and running webservice when lcoation is updated in background but it causes iphone heating up and battery Drains? Any one have solution for this ?

Comment: What is the root cause for heating up? You might look for `allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:` for saving power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting your position drains power, you can do few things to avoid that:

- use significant location changes (it is good if you do not need precise locations per time)
- limit the accuracy (changing this can make you avoid the use of GPS that it is really a battery drainer)

I'm do not understand the heat, yes GPS make the device become hotter, but I've never experienced a restart due to heat.
Are you sure that you are not getting also into an expensive computational tasks?, you can check this by using profiler or the later versions of xcode.
You can also set the distance filter, this will continue to get the position (it will not reduce the battery drain) but will call the delagate callback only when the distance threshold is reached.
On iOS6 it has been introduced also the concept of [deferring location updates in background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:timeout:), that probably is the best solution also for managing network traffic outgoing from your device.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you have only the decision between low location accuracy (1000km) and high (3-6m).
In the first case the GPS chip is disabled, in the second it is enabled.

If it is enabled, and you need that precise locations you can do nothing.
GPS needs power, and that power last for a bit more than 8 hours full precision locations (measured on my iphone4)

warming up is no problem, however I cannot remember a warming up on my phone caused by GPS (I will check that soon). But for sure it never warms up so much that it will restart,
So your case this is a bit strange, that also could be a defect of your device.

The cause for warming up can be also that you try to comminicate very often with the server.
You can check that yourself, just download a decent GPS aplication, and let it record a track.
If it does get hot too, your device might have a problem. (Or you are living in a extremly hot environment and the sun shines strongly on your phone.) 
Test also by disabling your network code.